# How do I put a texture on top of a normal map?

Tags: texturing, normal-map

I recently downloaded a model and it came with two images, a normal map and an image for colors. How do I put both of them on the model.

These are the two images 
[image]

[image]

Comment: What render engine are you using? Cycles or Blender Internal?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it in Cycles:

After adding both images in *Image Texture* nodes.
Plug your color map into the Color socket of a *Diffuse BSDF* shader node.
Take the normal map Image Texture, make sure to set it to "*Non-Color Data*" and plug it in to the *Color* socket of a *Normal Map* node. Then, link normal map to the *Normal* socket of the same *Diffuse BSDF* that the color map was linked to earlier.

[image: cycles material nodes]